# Combine two SELECT queries from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

**Issue**

I have one table (`posts`) with articles and article meta.

Another table (`post_reviews`) contains user-submitted ratings (a value out of 5) for each article, referencing `posts` by the `id` of the post in question.

I am trying to find the top three posts, by review, of the last 3 days. Therefore I need to:

- find all the posts in that time period (3 days)
- find the average rating for each post
- sort them by average rating (desc)

**Code**

For the first part, I can successfully use the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `hub_id`=:hub_id AND `date`>=:start_date AND `date`<=:end_date)
```

To find each individual post's average rating, I use this query:

```
SELECT SUM(`review`) AS `total` FROM `post_reviews` WHERE `id`=:id
```

then get the number of rows from this to work out the average:

```
SELECT * FROM `post_reviews` WHERE `post_id`=:id
```

How can I combine these three, or process this data so I can order the posts in a time period by the average rating?

**ANSWER**

The end result looks like this:

```
SELECT   `posts`.`id`, avg(`post_reviews`.`review`) as `average`
FROM     `posts` 
JOIN     `post_reviews` ON (`posts`.`id`=`post_reviews`.`post_id`)
WHERE    `hub_id`=:hub_id
    AND `posts`.`date`>=:start_date
    AND `posts`.`date`<=:end_date
GROUP BY `post_id`
ORDER BY avg(`review`) desc
```

Comment: Feels like it! But no, it's for a project I am working on. Why, can you think of an easier solution to this riddle?

Comment: DB Schema and sample data would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your `hub_id` represents, but I assume it's necessary; also assume the key field in Posts is `posts.post_id` and not `posts.id`:

```
SELECT   `p`.`id`, avg(`pr`.`review`) AS `average`
FROM     `posts`        AS `p`
JOIN     `post_reviews` AS `pr` ON (`p`.`id`=`pr`.`post_id`)
WHERE    `hub_id` =:hub_id
     AND `p`.`date` BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE-3 AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY `p`.`id`
ORDER BY avg(`review`) DESC;
```

See Example: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23693a/6)

Comment: This is phenomenal. I had to tweak a few things: (1) the `)` after `:end_date` stopped it processing so I took it out; (2) there is a `date` field in both tables so it became ambiguous so I had to change it to `posts.date` to be fine (but I didn't put that in the original post); (3) you were right, my mistake, it's `posts.id` not `posts.post_id`. I'm posting my code in the question but you're getting a tick for a brilliantly efficient answer.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan you're right, I noticed that when actually testing... check out the sqlfiddle that was added.  I'll make the changes, plus `total` is not a correct label, since it's an average.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the syntax for MySQL, but the would need a join and a group by. 
Something like....

```
SELECT post_id. avg(review)
FROM Posts P Inner Join Post_reviews PR on (p.post_id = pr.Post_id)
WHERE `hub_id`=:hub_id AND `date`>=:start_date AND `date`<=:end_date)
Group by Post_id
order by 2 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that works with sqlfiddle to prove it.

```
SELECT 
  p.hub_id
 ,p.post_id
 ,p.article
 ,p.articleMeta
 ,p.date
 ,IFNULL(AVG(r.ratings), 0) averageRating
FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN post_reviews r ON
    r.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE 
    hub_id = 1 
  AND date >= CURDATE() - 3
  AND date <= CURDATE()
GROUP BY 
  p.hub_id
 ,p.post_id
 ,p.article
 ,p.articleMeta
 ,p.date
ORDER BY
  p.date DESC
 ,averageRating DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39315/1